# Defining polynomial with exact roots

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand this question:

Prove that there exists a polynomial $p \in P_n(F) $ with exactly $m$ distinct roots, with $m \leq n$.

To me, the first step would be to define the polynomial as so:

$ p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + ... + a_nz^n$, and we assume a root exists, so the following is true;

$p(z) = (z - \lambda)q(z)$, and either $z = \lambda$ or $q(z) = 0$.

Although this didn't seem to prove $m$ distinct roots, my professor took a completely different approach and defined the polynomial as:

$p(z) = (z - \lambda_1)(z - \lambda_2) ... (z-\lambda_{m})$ and then the distinct roots exists where $ m \leq n$

Why is it in this form and not as a standard polynomial form? This seems trivial, but I'm clearly not understanding the question. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm assuming that $P_n(F)$ is the set of polynomials of degree less than $n$ with coefficients in a field $F$.

From the wording of your question I deduce that you know that the product of two polynomials is again a polynomial and that $p(\lambda)=0$ if an only if $z-\lambda$ divides $p$. This means that by multiplying together the polynomials $z-\lambda_i$ for $i=1,\dotsc,m$ you obtain a polynomial $p$ such that $p(\lambda_i)=0$ for each $i$. Note that it has minimal degree as long as the $\lambda_i$ are distinct!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I knew it was a simple answer, but I couldn't wrap my head around the notation, thank -you! Although, what do you mean by minimal degree? Wouldn't it be that the polynomial will have exact $m$ roots, as long as these roots are distinct?

Comment: I mean that the polynomial $p$ we just defined divides every other polynomial which has roots $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_m$ (try to show why). This would not be the case if, say, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ (again, try to find a polynomial with roots $\lambda_i$ which is not divisible by $p$ in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$p(x)
=x^{n-m+1}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} (x-k)
$.
Then $p$
has the $m$ distinct roots
$0, 1, ..., m-1$
with the root at $0$
repeated
$n-m+1$ times
and the other roots
of multiplicity one
for a total of
$n$ roots.